# Not sure what to add to my routes to get icalendar gem link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, icalendar

My index page shows

```
<%= link_to 'Subscribe', icalendar_url(protocol: :webcal, format: :ics) %>
```

On my controller I have added

```
   respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.ics do
    cal = Icalendar::Calendar.new
    cal.x_wr_calname = 'Awesome Rails Calendar'
    cal.event do |e|
      e.scheduled_date     = @clients.scheduled_date
      e.summary     = '@clients.work_needed'
      e.description = '@clients.comments'
    end
    cal.publish
    render plain: cal.to_ical
  end
```

end

And added nothing to my client.rb

What should I do I get the error

```
undefined method `icalendar_url' for #<#<Class:0x007fbb1a4b92b8>:0x007fbb32fc8560>
```

Comment: Make sure it is file prompt to download in usual browser, not plain output.

Comment: @Alex Khimich it isn’t prompting anything at present

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I was trying to fix the issue in routes, the route was wrong in the link nothing to do with routes

I had a link set as

```
<%= link_to "CSV", calendar_path(format: "csv"), :class => 'glyphicon glyphicon-file' %>
```

The middle calendar_path wasn't my controller, my controller was clients_path

With a simple change

```
<%= link_to "CSV", clients_path(format: "csv"), :class => 'glyphicon glyphicon-file' %>
```

it works !